# Ajax request and populating

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, request

I've a question how can I do an AJAX request to a DB, in which I store tags, for **example (DB)**:

- ID | tag_name
- 1  | php
- 2  | mysql

  etc.

and then to populate this results into : `availableTags: ["tag1", "tag2", "tag3"];`

**the script :**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#mytags").addtags({
        availableTags: ["tag1", "tag2", "tag3"]
    });
});
```

**EDIT:**

My question is exactly how to render the results and put any of the tags names into separate brackets and they should be coma separated like this : `["tag1","tag2" etc.]`

Comment: Did you even try Google?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make a file that gets you the needed return on request.
2. Do an AJAX request as described in the [jquery manual](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)*
3. ....
4. profit!

*code:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "yourURL.php",
  context: document.body,
  success: function(){
    //DO YOUR STUFF HERE. Probably something with the tags and all
  }
});
```